# Automatic translate Generic Access Rights within a report script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to obtain a simple report about Folder Security that I have to use in official documentation that need to be easy and clear for non-technical people.

I have found and adapt some code, but generic access rights are displayed as number so completely  not-easy to explain and report

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$IntPath = Get-Folder
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path $IntPath -Recurse -Force
$FolderName = Get-Item -Path $IntPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$date = Get-Date -UFormat %Y%m%d_%H%M%S
$Report = @()

Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
        {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD Group or User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
            $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
}

$Report | Export-Csv -path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\"$FolderName"_"$date".csv

# 268435456 --> FullControl
# -536805376 --> Modify, Synchronize
# -1610612736 --> ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
```

I would find a solution that will translate in the final CSV the number in the commments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your code like below works for me (PS version 5.1 of Windows 10 Pro):

```
function Get-Folder($initialDirectory) {
    # [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName() is deprecated
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $dialog.Description = "Select a folder"
    $dialog.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($dialog.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        $folder += $dialog.SelectedPath
    }
    $dialog.Dispose()

    return $folder
}

$SelectedPath = Get-Folder
$FolderName   = Get-Item -Path $SelectedPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$FolderPath   = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $SelectedPath -Recurse -Force
$date         = '{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}' -f (Get-Date)
$outputFile   = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$FolderName_$date.csv"

# collect the objects returned
$Report = foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'FolderName'       = $Folder.FullName
            'AD Group or User' = $Access.IdentityReference
            'Permissions'      = $Access.FileSystemRights.ToString()
            'Inherited'        = $Access.IsInherited
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$Report | Format-Table -AutoSize

# export to csv file
$Report | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

If for some reason you still get numeric values instead of strings for the `FileSystemRights`, you can use a switch like this to convert the numbers to descriptive strings:

```
# collect the objects returned
$Report = foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access) {
        # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights
        $permissions = switch($Access.FileSystemRights.value__) {
            2032127     { 'FullControl '; break}
            1179785     { 'Read '; break}
            1180063     { 'Read, Write '; break}
            1179817     { 'ReadAndExecute '; break}
            1245631     { 'ReadAndExecute, Modify, Write '; break}
            1180095     { 'ReadAndExecute, Write '; break}
            268435456   { 'FullControl (Sub Only) '; break}
            -1610612736 { 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize '; break}
            -536805376  { 'Modify, Synchronize '; break}
            default     { $Access.FileSystemRights.ToString()}
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'FolderName'       = $Folder.FullName
            'AD Group or User' = $Access.IdentityReference
            'Permissions'      = $permissions
            'Inherited'        = $Access.IsInherited
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

The above is a listing of the most common file permissions. File objects can have a lot more permission values set in the [Access Mask Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask-format) flags value.

The `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights` enumeration stores these values, mapping the most common values to human readable words:

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> ListDirectory                      1
> ReadData                           1
> WriteData                          2
> CreateFiles                        2
> CreateDirectories                  4
> AppendData                         4
> ReadExtendedAttributes             8
> WriteExtendedAttributes           16
> Traverse                          32
> ExecuteFile                       32
> DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles      64
> ReadAttributes                   128
> WriteAttributes                  256
> Write                            278
> Delete                         65536
> ReadPermissions               131072
> Read                          131209
> ReadAndExecute                131241
> Modify                        197055
> ChangePermissions             262144
> TakeOwnership                 524288
> Synchronize                  1048576
> FullControl                  2032127
> ```

Looking at the AccessMask in above link, you can encounter values that aren't in this enumeration and in order to translate all of this into words, you could try something like below.
It uses the `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights` enumeration sorted in **reverse** order by `Value` and stored in a variable `$FileSystemRights`.
Variable `$value` is the numeric value you obtained from `$Access.FileSystemRights.value__`.

```
$PermsList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
#if ($value -band 0xF1000000) {
    # Generic access rights (bits 24..31)
    if ($value -band 0x80000000) { [void]$PermsList.AddRange([string[]]('Read', 'ReadAttributes', 'ReadExtendedAttributes', 'Synchronize'))}     # GENERIC_READ
    if ($value -band 0x40000000) { [void]$PermsList.AddRange([string[]]('Write', 'WriteAttributes', 'WriteExtendedAttributes', 'Synchronize'))}  # GENERIC_WRITE
    if ($value -band 0x20000000) { [void]$PermsList.AddRange([string[]]('ReadAndExecute', 'ReadAttributes', 'ReadPermissions'))}                 # GENERIC_EXECUTE
    if ($value -band 0x10000000) { [void]$PermsList.Add('FullControl')}                                                                          # GENERIC_All
    if ($value -band 0x1000000)  { [void]$PermsList.Add('ChangePermissions')}                                                                    # Right to access SACL
#}

# Standard access and Object specific rights (bits 0..23)
$value = $value -band 0xFFFFFF
$FileSystemRights | ForEach-Object {
    if (($value -band $_.Value)) { [void]$PermsList.Add($_.Name) }
}

($PermsList.ToArray() | Select-Object -Unique) -join ', '
```

The values you mention in the comment would return:

```
-2147483648 --> 'Read, ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, Synchronize'
-268435456  --> 'Read, ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, Synchronize, Write, WriteAttributes, WriteExtendedAttributes, ReadAndExecute, ReadPermissions, FullControl'
-1073741760 --> 'Read, ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, Synchronize, Write, WriteAttributes, WriteExtendedAttributes, FullControl, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles'
```

Hope this explains more about the different file object permissions.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't Understand how does it works... It is the same identical script just reorganized. I need that if the script find a row like: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Acronis\BackupAndRecoveryConsole NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller 268435456                        True

268435456 will be translated in FullControl in the final CSV.

Comment: @PietroOttati What version of PowerShell are you on?

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1018

Comment: @PietroOttati So we're on the same version. As said, on My machine I get descriptions like `FullControl`, `Modify, Synchronize` etc. both on screen and in the CSV. Did you try my code?

Comment: Hi Theo of course I've tried the First part. Nothing changed. I didnt quite catch ho ti merge the second part. Sorry I'm a newbie that trying to manage the learning curve... :-P

Comment: @PietroOttati Very strange that on your machine you get numbers instead of descriptions here..  You can combine the `switch` part by adding it just above the `[PSCustomObject]@{` line. Then change `'Permissions' = $Access.FileSystemRights.ToString()` into `'Permissions' = $permissions`

Comment: I've tried on a bigger folder just to test it and I received other 3 codes:

-2147483648
-268435456
-1073741760

So I imagine that they are not translated because they are not present in the $permissions switch list... The question is how can I find this code meaning or all the possible code and their own translation? I googled them and I can't find the direct translation... :-(

Comment: @PietroOttati I have updated my answer to hopefully explain more about the different FileSystemRights values you can get. I have added code for you to figure out the values that do not translate into words. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for you help... honestly I've got lost at the moment moreover I'm not able to run correctly $PermList etc etc script.... honestly Windows permissions are really a mess... I have 2 questions minus sign in this 268435456 and -268435456 are the same or not? In other words the sign has a meaning?? Second question why if I use: <pre>$Report | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation<code> instead of <pre> $Report | Export-Csv -path $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\"$FolderName"_"$date".csv<code> I didn't receive the same filename???

Comment: @PietroOttati The minus sign comes from the fact that the most significant bit (bit nr. 31) is set to 1. In this case, it represents the bit for `GENERIC_READ`. Signed integer values in that case are regarded negative values. In fact, the value is a 32-bit Flags value and actually should be looked at in an Unsigned fashion. You can read about binary values [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering). As for the second question, You are quoting the path wrong. The path only needs double quotes around the whole thing `"$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$FolderName_$date.csv"`.